# Where do I install NuGet Package

Tags: azure, azure-caching

My solution consist of 3 projects: A Core, Library and AzureWorkerRole.

I want to know in which project should I run "PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching"... technically the cache will be co-located with "AzureWorkerRole", but the "Core" will be the only project to really access the cache...

so should I install it on the Core, AzureWorkerRole or both?

Comment: I'd say try it without, then add it in projects where it crashes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker role project will have necessary dependencies when you configure it for caching via the properties dialog window.

Then you need to add reference to the caching assembly only to the project that uses the cache, and make sure you mark it with `True` value for the `Copy Local` attribute.